# CAST - Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

I have been using ChromeCast in my application before and it was working great. Recently I added Google Cloud Messaging in my application too, and for that I had to update dependency files to 
`'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0'` and `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'`. But now when client disconnects chromecast we get the following fatal exceptions and the application crashes.

```
11-23 12:42:49.415  22117-22117/com.jadoo.jadooplus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jadoo.jadooplus, PID: 22117
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:315)
        at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:512)
        at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteControllerDialog.onCreate(MediaRouteControllerDialog.java:178)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:396)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:268)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:399)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1813)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:989)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

preceded by an `InvocationTargetException` and `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Even now when I change the version anywhere below 7.5.x the code works great. Any ideas why ImageButton is not drawable. I've spent a day at following the stacktrace and today surfing the web, no luck. I haven't found anything useful on the topic.

I applologize for not posting stacktrace from other exception' stacktrace but I can't add more in formatted code.

**Edit 1:** I can't seem to add any more code here so here's a snapshot:

[image: snapshot]

**Edit 2:** 
I have already tried disabling Proguard, with no effect. The issue persists on a LG G2 d802, a range of Samsung Tabs and Nexus 7. Also I am not using CastCompanionLibrary.

Comment: Can you add the missing part of the stack trace? In particular the part relevant to `Resources$NotFoundException`. Apparently a resource couldn't be found/resolved at runtime - You can look up the resource name in your `R` file using the id value from the strack trace. It may also be worth mentioning some of the device characteristics that generate the error (i.e. version of Android, screen size/dp etc).

Comment: Also, if you run Proguard on your build, try disabling it to see if the problem persists. Or, try with `shrinkResources false` to ensure Proguard didn't accidentally remove the resource.

Comment: I can't seem to add any more in the post via 'Code Sample'. I will try disabling proguard.

Comment: @MH. Disabling proguard doesn't work. Should I take a snippet and add the image of the exception?

Comment: Sure, or paste the stack trace text someplace public and then I'll edit it into your question. Forgot to ask by the way, but are you using the cast companion library? And could you also list the gradle/build tools version?

Comment: @MH. I have tested this bug on multiple devices and OS platforms include LG G2 d802, a Range of Samsung Tabs and Nexus 7. Also I am not using CastCompanionLibrary

Comment: Ok, cool. Can you open up the generated `R` file for your app and search what resource `0x7f01008d` belongs to?

Comment: @MH. `0x7f01008d` points to the background of ImageButtons used in various layouts. So does that tell us the background property cannot be accessed for whatever ImageButton is used when user clicks to disconnect from ChromeCast?

Comment: Is that a drawable you created yourself or one that ships with the play-services-cast library? It may be helpful to know its contents. According to the strack trace Android expected a drawable resource but found an attribute resource identifier instead.